# Injecting eventloggers with different configurations in ASP.NET app

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, logging, dependency-injection

In a ASP.NET Core5 app:

I'd like to inject a logger like this:

```
public class X { 
    X( ILogger<X> loggerX )...
}

public class Y { 
    X( ILogger<Y> loggerY )...
}
```

When I inject these loggers I'd like both loggers to log to the Windows Eventlog, but I'd like loggerX to set the Source field to "X" and loggerY to set the Source field to "Y".

This way, I'd be able to differentiate easily between logs generated by either class. (The classes in my case would typically be controllers).

My question is:

How do I configure the loggers in the DI container to have this behaviour? (customized logger configuration based on the type of logger extracted).

And also, is there a way to configure the DI Container so that the above scenario would create loggerX to write to a new Log called "X" and logger "Y" to a log called "Y" ? (So, instead of setting the Source, write to different logs).....

Finally, and I realize that this might be asking for a lot, but I may as well ask and learn... Is there a way to achieve the above through "mostly" configuration(appsettings.json) instead of writing loads of code? I don't mind writing the code, but I am trying to make as much as possible configurable where I can and where it makes sense.

Comment: The `X` and `Y` types are uses as the logger's category. You can specify different settings based on category. The default `appsettings.json` files already specify different logging levels for different categories like `Microsoft`

Comment: As for storing to logs, that's not provided out of the box. You need a separate logging library or provider to log to files, eg Serilog. Which library are you using?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The logging category sounds interesting thanks - that might be worth pursuing.  With regards to the storing of logs - I didn't mean filesystem storage, I was actually referring to "Custom Eventlogs" .... So, similar to the Application eventlog - but you can define your own eventlogs. (See "Applications and Service logs" in the eventlog viewer). But to answer your question - I'm using Vanilla .NET at the moment - trying quite hard to not add an external logging library unless I really have to....... (my needs are modest for the most part)

Answer (score 1):

I know 2 way  for this issue:

First way :

1.Regsiter services in Startup class

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddTransient<IMessageService, EmailService>();
        services.AddTransient<IMessageService, SmsService>();
    }
```

2.Resolve Services

```
 public MessagesController(IEnumerable<IMessageService> messageServices)
    {
        _messageServices = messageServices;
    }

     var emailService = _messageServices.OfType<EmailService>().First();
     var messageServices = serviceProvider.GetServices<IMessageService>();
```

Second way

1.Regsiter services in Startup class

```
        services.AddTransient<EmailService>();
        services.AddTransient<SmsService>();
        services.AddTransient<Func<MessageServiceType, IMessageService>>(serviceProvider => key =>
        {
            switch (key)
            {
                case MessageServiceType.EmailService:
                    return serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<EmailService>();
                case MessageServiceType.SmsService:
                    return serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<SmsService>();
                default:
                    throw new NotImplementedException($"Service of type {key} is not implemented.");
            }
        });
```

2.Resolve services

```
private readonly Func<MessageServiceType, IMessageService> _messageServiceResolver;

    public MessagesController(Func<MessageServiceType, IMessageService> messageServiceResolver)
    {
        _messageServiceResolver = messageServiceResolver;
    }
public IActionResult Index()
{
   var emailService = _messageServiceResolver(MessageServiceType.EmailService);
 
   return View();
}
```

Comment: This is a nice explanation of how to do DI. My question was specifically around how to configure the logger class though.  We inject classes all over the place already - I'm really asking how to configure the logger differently when it is injected into different classes.